# Handle "FileLoadException" when reference to class library is missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I've written a DLL/class library which I'm using in a few of my application.  I have a reference to the library in the project references and I declare an instant of the library in the "Public Class" of the form as follows (i.e. not inside a Sub or Function):

```
Dim myLibrary As New MyHelperLibrary.MyHelperLibraryClass
```

I like to try to handle any errors rather than the user seeing the dreaded Unhandled Exception window, but if, for whatever reason, my library was missing or had been deleted, I don't seem to be able to handle the exception it generates:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyHelperLibrary, Version=0.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=45f96d659b47asd9' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is there a way to handle the above situation?  Obviously I can't put a Try/Catch around the Dim as it's outside a method, but I'm not even sure if it's that line causing the error, or just the fact that there's a project reference that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, instance object of third-part library directly in the global scope isn't a good practice, because it can lead up to situations like the one you have mentioned.

You should move the instantiation of the variables on a constructor or load method of the class that will use them.

EX:

```
Class MyClass

    Dim myLibrary As MyHelperLibrary.MyHelperLibraryClass

    Private Sub New()
        myLibrary = New MyHelperLibrary.MyHelperLibraryClass
    End Sub

End Class
```

OR:

```
Class MyClass

    Dim myLibrary As MyHelperLibrary.MyHelperLibraryClass

    Public Sub Main()
        myLibrary = New MyHelperLibrary.MyHelperLibraryClass
    End Sub

End Class
```

In this way, you can wrap the instantiation with a try/catch block.

Another way is to handle Application.UnhandledException

```
Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
    MsgBox(e.Exception.Message ) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not even sure if it's that line causing the error

It is, but not where you think.  The exception is generated by the jitter, *before* any code that actually uses the type even starts running.  Being just-in-time, that will typically be in whatever method makes a call into the class.  It is the jitter that needs the assembly first in order to generate the code.  The exception will be raised in the code that makes the call, not anywhere near your class.

It gets worse from there.  When you run the release build, the jitter may inline a method from your class into the code that calls the method.  Now the exception is raised in the method that calls the method that calls into your class.  The possible number of places the exception can be raised can be quite large if your assembly has a non-trivial number of public classes with a non-trivial number of public members.  Hundreds is possible.

If this starts the sound like a Really Bad Idea then, yes, it is.